# implicit multivariable derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I didn't really understand how implicit multi-variable  functions are derived; I thought of another method which may fit and may not; suppose we have $xy^2z^3=8$ and we want to derive it; it is the same as $xy^2z^3 -8 =0$

or $ F(x,y,z) = 0 $

hence $ F(x,y,z) = xy^2z^3 -8 $

Therefore $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} $, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} $, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} $ are in fact the partial derivatives of the implicit function that we sought. The three are also the coordinates of the normal at a certain point and of the gradient.

makes sense?

Comment: The words after "Therefore" are not clear to me.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really say anything regarding your statement

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't do it like this.

There is a 3D surface given by the equation $F(x,y,z)=0$. You want to know, if you can describe this surface as a function $z=z(x,y)$ (for example). The implicit function theorem gives you an answer, when you can do it. So, the implicit function is the function $z$ not the function $F$ ($F$ just gives you the surface). It is implicit, because it is given by an equation ($F=0$) not by explicit formula ($z(x,y)=...$).

Then you have $$F(x,y,z(x,y))=0,$$
what you can partially differentiate (when?) with respect to $x$ and get
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0,$$
which gives you the formula for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. 
This is just the basic concept of course.

Comment: F is a function of 3 variables giving out a fourth output...not a 3D surface....

Comment: a tesseract maybe....that doesn't matter since in order to derive the function I need it to be a part of a function of a higher order....that said could you derive this function the way you said and find it's plane at (1,-1,2)? we will compare results then...

Comment: Exactly, $F:R^3\rightarrow R$ is a function of three variables. You can imagine the graph of it in $R^4$ (if you can).  But, by setting $F(x,y,z)=0$ you are making a cut of the graph in $R^4$ by the hyperplane, what is surface in 3D. I think it is useful to imagine it firstly for F(x,y)=0.  By saying "$F$ just gives you the surface" I meant that setting it equal to $0$ gives the surface. Sorry for confusing :)

Comment: I cant unless Im an alien from the fifth dimension or something...I'm setting $F(x,y,z) = xy^2z^3 -8$ as the function then derive partially

Comment: I don't derive F(x,y,z)=0